# Undefined variable result when trying to echo a value from a query using php

Tags: php

I am trying to get some information out of a query and into the values of some inputs, the parameter that it sends to display the specific information is a ID that is being send like this:

PHP on a includes file:

```
<a href="modificarLab.php?idlab='.$row['idlab'] .'">

<input type = "submit" value = "Modificar" class= "btnModificar" id = "btnModificar-'.$row['idlab'].'" 
style="position:absolute;left:170px;top:192px;"/>

</a>
```

When I click the above link it sends me to another page that reflects the idlab on the URL, so it shows idlab= X, where x depends on the idlab of the button clicked, this part seems to be working just fine.

The problem comes when trying to get the information into the inputs'values, in a example I used as reference they used the exact same syntax (including the part above with the href)and it is working, so I don't know what could I be doing wrong. This is how my code looks:

On the page the href refers to:

**UPDATED php:**

```
      <?php

      isset($_POST['lab']) ? $_POST['lab'] : 'Unknown';

            $result = getSpecificLabModify($_GET['lab']);

     ?>


  <form id="frmLabs" method="post">

  <?php
  if (isset($_GET['idlab'])){

        $result = getSpecificLabModify($_GET['idlab']);
     }
 ?>


<label for="txtCapacidad">Capacidad</label>
  <input type="text" name="txtCapacidad" id="txtCapacidad" value="<?php echo utf8_encode($result['capacidad'])?>">

  <label for="txtNumLab">Código de laboratorio</label>
  <input type="text" name="txtNumLab" id="txtNumLab" value="<?php echo utf8_encode($result['codigolab'])?>">
  <label for="txtUbicacion">Ubicación</label>
  <input type="text" name="txtUbicacion" id="txtUbicacion" value="<?php echo utf8_encode($result['ubicacion'])?>">
```

But instead of the values inside I am getting the error:

**EDIT ERROR:**

**Notice:**  Undefined index: idlab in C:\wamp\www\Proyecto\modificarLab.php on line 66
Just in case the function to get the information is this one:

On the includes PHP file:

```
function getSpecificLabModify($pId){

    $query = "SELECT * FROM labs WHERE idlab=$pId";


    $result =  do_query($query);

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);


    return $row;
}
```

I've tried a lot of things but so far nothing has yielded any results. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$_GET['idlab']` is not set

Comment: That is what I don't get! The example I saw used the exact same thing. I literally tried to copy paste and replace variables but nothing....

Comment: I even used the code you gave me yesterday to try and patch things up but nada.

Comment: Only change is the error: : Undefined index: idlab which is bollocks because when I tried a long winded way to make it work it called the function but instead displayed the information in a mess.

Comment: What you need to do is find out why it isn't set. Is it present in the URL that loads this page?

Comment: It is. And it is successfully changing its value depending on the element I click.

Comment: Put `print_r($_GET);` at the top of the page and let me know what it says.

Comment: @John Conde Array ( [lab] => 1 )

Comment: When I choose another element it is successfully reflecting that element's id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `$_GET` not `$_POST`. So change:

```
isset($_POST['lab']) ? $_POST['lab'] : 'Unknown';
```

to:

```
isset($_GET['lab']) ? $_GET['lab'] : 'Unknown';
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, you're a hero to me.